# How do I create multiple iterating clickable divs with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create multiple divs that sit within a predefined html container that scrolls horizontally. I can get the javascript to create the divs and give them an id with an iterating number but I need them to be wrapped in an `<a>` tag so they're a clickable link.

Here is the code without the `<a>` tag added (30 divs are created correctly) :

```
var adoptionSqs  = 30;
var adoptionID = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < adoptionSqs; i++) {

  var divElement = document.createElement("div");
  divElement.id = ("rewild-" + adoptionID);

  document.getElementById("rewild-the-valley").appendChild(divElement);

  var element = document.getElementById("rewild-" + adoptionID);
  element.classList.add("one");
  element.classList.add("slide");

  adoptionID ++
}
```

Here is the code with the `<a>` tag added (only 1 `<a>` tag and 1 div are created) :

```js
var adoptionSqs = 30;
var adoptionID = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < adoptionSqs; i++) {
  var adoptionA = document.createElement("a");
  adoptionA.href = ("rewild-" + adoptionID);

  var divElement = document.createElement("div");
  divElement.id = ("rewild-" + adoptionID);

  adoptionA.appendChild(divElement);
  document.getElementById("rewild-the-valley").appendChild(adoptionA);

  var element = document.getElementById("rewild-" + adoptionID);
  element.classList.add("one");
  element.classList.add("slide");

  adoptionID++
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slide {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 4000px;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
  transform-origin: top left;
  background: url("https://tirnatur.digitalpercolator.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/Clouds-scaled.jpg");
}

.one {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.6;
  background-size: auto 80vh;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  width: 400vw;
}

.one:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

.outer-wrapper {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vw;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100vh);
  transform-origin: top left;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper" id="rewild-the-valley">

  </div>
```

Comment: Try adding onclick attribute to div

Comment: Why give a jsfiddle link instead of putting a Stack Snippet in the question?

Comment: When I inspect the page, I see all 30 `<a>` tags. Why do you think only 1 is created?

Comment: My apologies, I didn't know how to add a Stack Snippit. When I inspected it in JS Fiddle earlier it was only giving me 1 but it seems to be creating all 30 now. My mistake. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is work just fine....

Click to see the picture.

[I inspect your Code in my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0iZ4.png)

Comment: My apologies, it does seem to be working now. Sorry!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).